# Fast USB stick slow as boot medium?

Tags: linux, usb-boot

There are two USB flash drives I currently use as boot media:

- SanDisk Extreme 16 GB (USB 3.0a) with Read/Write ~245/50 MB/s
- Transcend JF780 128 GB (USB 3.0a/3.1) with Read/Write ~210/140 MB/s

I can `dd` my Linux installation (14 GB VHD excluding the VHD footer) onto the flash drives and after fixing the GPT, so that it fits the respective flash drive's storage capacity, I can boot both on my machine... With one little problem: The JF780 when used as boot medium suddenly becomes insanely slow; The boot process takes forever and, when it finishes someday, commands in terminal hang themselves, whereas the Extreme operates just fine. On the other hand the JF780 hasn't got these issues when used like it is supposed to (i.e. data storage). **What might cause this behavior? Could it be the flash drive's fault or limitations of Linux? Is there a way to find out what causes these problems, so I can try fixing them if possible?**

Comment: I doubt the medium got slow... Some service is taking forever to start, turn off the splash screen and watch the boot up to see where it pauses, or check dmesg and other logs and look for a big time gap.

Comment: Have you tried the USB on another machine?

Comment: @TimmyJim Not yet, there's no UEFI based machine available to me except my one. I just configured my system to boot directly into TTY (by setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`), so I can see whether or not my desktop is causing this. Maybe I can even get the logs from `dmesg`

Comment: I like it when you say that *commands hang themselves*...

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. USB stick was fast when used as storage medium. As boot medium extemely slow.

Slowness occured when I used a hub like docking station or monitor with USB-ports. When hub was used BIOS used USB stick as USB 1.1 device. This happened only when my stick was used as boot medium.

Without the hubs I got my USB stick to work fast as boot medium.

Comment: That's interesting. But I don't think that my BIOS is causing the problem, because I'm using the same USB port on my laptop for both USB sticks.